# What are the differences between a linear logic based planner and a first order logic based planner

Tags: first-order-logic, artificial-intelligence, linear-logic

Linear logic based planners and first order logic based planners must have different strengths and weaknesses. I would appreciate help in understanding what these strengths and weaknesses are and uderstanding situations where one is more appropriate than the other.